# Reporting services + sort expression

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

Greetings, 
In my reporting services I would like to add sorting. Is there any way I can add sorting by two fields inside one column's sort expression? something like:

```
=Fields!SomeValue1.Value
=Fields!Somevalue2.Value
```

when I use this sort expression, values are not sorted correctly. 
Values I would like to sort are something like

```
SomeValue1    SomeValue2
10            11
9             1
20            21
13            12
13            7
17            6
```

The case is that SomeValue1 and SomeValue2 comes from another value that as follows:

```
10-11
9-1
20-21
13-12
13-7
17-6
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three possiblities:

1. (Simplest) Include an `order by SomeValue1, SomeValue2` clause at the end of your SQL query.
2. Sort by *two* expressions in Table Properties - ie. in the Sorting tab in the Table Properties dialog, enter `=Fields!SomeValue1.Value` as the expression on the first line, then click on the line below and enter `=Fields!SomeValue2.Value` - like so:
   [image]
3. (Hardest) Sort on a single expression in Table Properties consisting of SomeValue1 and SomeValue2 converted to 0-padded, fixed length strings, concatenated together - similar to the original value, but formatted consistently, like so: `0000000001-0000000001`.

I recommend the first approach.

Comment: I have resolved it in that way: =Cint(Fields!SomeValue1.Value * 1000 + Fields!SomeValue2.Value)

Comment: That will work, too (as long as SomeValue2 doesn't go above 999).